# How to get (or make) a reference to the InputConnection of an Android EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

I am making a custom keyboard that I want to include in an app. I already know [how to make a system keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44939816/3681880). I don't want to do that because it requires installing by the user.

Whenever the user presses a key on the keyboard it should send the key text to whichever `EditText` currently has focus (if any).

The [documentation states](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html)

> An editor needs to interact with the IME, receiving commands through
>   this `InputConnection` interface, and sending commands through
>   `InputMethodManager`.

This is illustrated in the following image (where `View` is an `EditText`).

[image]

This makes it sound like I should be using an input connection to communicate with the `EditText`. So my question is, how does my custom keyboard view get a reference to the currently focused `EditText`'s  input connection. Or how does it start that connection?

Related

- [How to send key event to an edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779000/how-to-send-key-event-to-an-edit-text)
- [Custom 'Keyboard' built in an application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196511/custom-keyboard-built-in-an-application-on-android)
- [Want custom keyboard to ONLY be used for MY APP and restore previous when app loses focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145191/want-custom-keyboard-to-only-be-used-for-my-app-and-restore-previous-when-app-lo)
- [Android development: Custom keyboard](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm)

Comment: `View#onCreateInputConnection` ?

Comment: the docs say: *"Create a new InputConnection for an InputMethod to interact with the view. The default implementation returns null, since it doesn't support input methods. You can override this to implement such support. This is only needed for views that take focus and text input."*

Comment: @pskink Oh, I read your first comment too quickly. I thought it said something like `getInputConnection`. I have overridden `onCreateInputConnection` to make a custom `EditText` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44342915/3681880) and [here](https://github.com/suragch/mongol-library/blob/master/mongol-library/src/main/java/net/studymongolian/mongollibrary/MongolEditText.java)). Now I am trying to go the other way, that is, make the IME that talks to the `EditText`.

Comment: So the EditText's `onCreateInputConnection` returns an input connection, but how does my keyboard get a hold of it?

Comment: inside `InputMethodManager#startInputInner`

Comment: @pskink, [this looks complicated](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.java#L1146) but I will study how Android did it. Thanks.

Comment: yes, line 1200: `InputConnection ic = view.onCreateInputConnection(tba);`

Comment: @pskink, I always associate `onDoSomething` methods with listeners or something you override in a subclass. I assumed only the system calls these type of methods directly. It took me a while to realize that I could call it directly myself. You seem to always answer my questions in the comments. If you want to add it as an answer, I will change the accepted answer to yours. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @pskink mentioned in the comments, you can use

```
InputConnection ic = editText.onCreateInputConnection(new EditorInfo());
```

to get a reference to an `EditText`'s input connection.

It can be handed off to a custom keyboard when the `EditText` receives focus by adding a listener.

```
// get the input connection from the currently focused edit text
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            InputConnection ic = editText.onCreateInputConnection(new EditorInfo());
            keyboard.setInputConnection(ic); // custom keyboard method
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
InputConnection ic = v.onCreateInputConnection(new EditorInfo());
```